# Acceder a datos de tabla en una relacion muchos a muchos con mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una bd que contiene dos tablas, la tabla productos y la tabla categorías, éstas dos tablas tienen la relación muchos es a muchos por lo cual se me crea una tercer tabla al crear esta relación, mi pregunta ahora es como yo puedo acceder a los datos almacenados en estas dos tablas, es decir, cual seria la consulta sql para poder ver cuáles son las categorías que tiene un producto, y cuáles son los productos que tiene una categoría!?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para lograrlo debes realizar INNER JOINs, revisa la [documentacion](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) y verás que no es tan complicado. De todas maneras, sería bueno que pongas lo que has intentado hasta ahora.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Producto
INNER JOIN Producto_has_Categoria ON
Producto_has_Categoria.Producto_idProducto = Producto.idProducto
INNER JOIN Categoria ON
Producto_has_Categoria.Categoria_idCategoria = Categoria.idCategoria
WHERE Categoria.nombre = "nombre";
```

Comment: Si bien tu respuesta probablemente solucione la pregunta, es importante explicar el porque de la misma, para que pueda ayudar a otros usuarios. Además así tu respuesta no se reportará como de baja calidad. [answer].